# Linux rpm installs but cannot erase. Why?

Tags: linux, rpm

My Perl code installed several (4) rpm files as root. the next install removes them (`rpm -e`) before installing a newer version.  One does not remove, with `rpm -e` giving the error that it is not installed.  However, later when the updated file is installed, the message is given that it is already installed.

Manual attempts to remove give the same results.  My questions are how to force removal something from the rpm database, and why does this contradication exist (not installed from `rpm -e` and already installed from `rpm -Uvh` and `rpm -ivh`)?

Comment: Maybe it's better to post this question on superuser.com?! Also try: rpm -e --nodeps {package_name}

Answer (score 13):

1. Once installed, use the package name, not the package filename.
2. You should not need to remove a package before upgrading it. Doing so means that one or both of the packages are broken.

Answer (score 11):

The reason it is not erased is likely because one of the scriptlets is failing. Do it manually and watch for errors. If it mentions a failed scriptlet, try erasing it with `rpm -e --noscripts`

Comment: Thanks - this solved a problem I had with a package I built myself, which had an error in the pre-remove scriptlet.

Answer (score 3):

`rpm -e --force` will **not** forcibly remove a package, `rpm -e --nodeps` **will** by stopping it to check for other dependencies.

It's possible your RPM database is in some way bent out of shape, you may wish to try an `rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: Forcing an rpm remove in this fashion no longer works as of CentOS 6.4. Attempting a force returns the response: rpm: only installation, upgrading, rmsource and rmspec may be forced